# All Points Distance of 2 Away from the Unit Cube in R3

Tags: calculus, geometry

The official question reads:

"Find the volume of the region in R3 consisting of all points whose distance
to the unit cube {(x, y, z) : 0 ≤ x ≤ 1, 0 ≤ y ≤ 1, 0 ≤ z ≤ 1} is less than or equal to 2."

We are supposed to use "basic solid shapes" to solve this problem. My intuition tells me that there would be an eighth of a sphere, each with radius 2, surrounding each of the 8 vertices, as well as rectangular prisms with side lengths of 2,1,1 aligned with each of the 6 faces. So my result was 1/8*8*(4/3pi*2^3) + 6*2*1*1 = 12 + 32/3 pi. Does my reasoning make sense? Am I missing any shapes?

Comment: You are on the right track, but are not quite there yet. Have you considered what points are at distance $2$ from the edges?

Comment: You forget two pieces, 1) the unit cube itself. 2) the 12 quarter cylinders of length 1 and radius $2$ along the edges (as pointed out by Servaes before)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.